# How do I go about making a custom Android UI element reusable outside project?

Tags: android, user-interface, packaging

I have a fairly simple Android UI element that I created locally inside of a application project.  This element is a `EditText`/`Label` combination that displays the hint text in the `EditText` but when the user starts to type in the field it floats the hint text as a label above the field.
I would like to be able to use this component in other projects.  I've been unable to find any useful information about how to package separately from application so that I can reuse it in other places.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a library project. You can add to a library any classes that you want, including User Interface elements.

On your projects, you just add a reference to you library project to reuse it.

Check [this link](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html).

Comment: That is helpful.  I was hoping for something more like a aar or jar as opposed to a project in a shared IDE space.